# When running Ubuntu 20.04, using start command in the VSCode terminal gives "Permission Denied" error

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, permissions

I am trying to learn how to use CLI and am very new to Javascript, so my apologies in advance.

I'm running WSL Ubuntu for a class and trying to code in VSCode. I'm running into an error where I want to open the index.html file in my google chrome browser using the CLI so I figure I should use the 'start' command. I type into the VSCode terminal 'start index.html' and receive the following error:

/mnt/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/cmd: 8: : Permission denied

My research tells me I need to use chmod somewhere but I'm at a loss of where or exactly what I should be doing with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use WSL better source directory use better in WSL path.

My case is all working directory in WSL, and Termial start in WSL $home.
ex) git, npm, python, php etc. I just install all in WSL.

even If can access able windows folder will be slow.

my recommand is all command or tool install in WSL also work directory